# Can you create a default route in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, create-react-app

Is it were possible to have default routes in Next.js so all routes or a whitelist of routes will all go to a specific page.

For my project the idea is to use Next.js to build the marketing website, sign up and sign in process, and then to have a Next.js page that would boot up an SPA (probably using create-react-app and react-router) so that any route which isn't a Next.js page would assume that instead its a route in the SPA and would therefore direct to that page which would boot up the SPA

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. Missed it in the documentation

Answer (score 9):

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

```js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/redirectRoute',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

[Update: Next.js 14]
Config file is now saved as next.config.mjs (in latest version of Next.js). You may write following code instead.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/redirectRoute",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};

export default nextConfig;
```

Comment: To use Redirects you can use the redirects key in next.config.js:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One way that seems to work is to create a custom 404 page. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page

Every route that is not a recognised next.js route will call this page, but will not redirect (change the browser URL) which is exactly what's wanted when booting up an SPA.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a app/page.tsx (pages/page.tsx) and returned the default component like this: (I just needed a default page / entry-page for '/')

```
'use client';

import AboutUs from './aboutus/page'
const DfltPage = () => {
    return (<AboutUs/>)
}

export default DfltPage;
```

This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the main page "app/page"
return the layout and the page as its child like this

```
// page.jsx
import HomeLayout from "./home/layout";
import Home from "./home/page";

export default () => (
  <HomeLayout>
    <Home />
  </HomeLayout>
);
```